# Symfony2.8 how to list every URL's permission

Tags: list, symfony, acl

In Symfony 2.8.
I want to list every URL's permission(e.g.roles) in order to find which URL is not protected.
The list result format is same as security config about access_control option.
How to do ?

Comment: You want to setup a request listener and log all of the roles each route requires? Can you provide some examples of how your routes are setup and how you are checking permissions now?

Comment: Every routes are annotation format in controller.I want to find those routes that are not set permissions.It likes scan all route URLs  that  not protected.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know and after some research what you are looking for doesnt exist out of the box. You could look into expanding the `php bin/console debug:router` command to include what security checks exist for each.

Another option would be to manually go through all the routes listed in the debug output and look at the security requirements in the `_profiler`.

Comment: I can get all routes ,while I don't know how to check whether protected.